# Laravel Socialite Remember Me

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am using [Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) for user logins and I would like to set a `remember_token` to remember the user when they login through Socialite.

Right now I have the following service to create or log the user in:

```
class SocialAccountService {

    public function createOrGetUser(ProviderUser $providerUser) {

        $account = SocialAccount::whereProvider('google')
            ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
            ->first();

        if ($account) {
            return $account->user;
        } else {
            $account = new SocialAccount([
                'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'provider' => 'google'
            ]);

            $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();
            if (!$user) {
                $user = User::create([
                    'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                    'name' => $providerUser->getName()
                ]);
            }
            $account->user()->associate($user);
            $account->save();
            return $user;
        }
    }
}
```

It is called with the following controller:

```
class AuthController extends Controller {

    public function logout() {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function redirectToGoogle() {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleGoogleCallback(SocialAccountService $service) {
        $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('google')->user());
        auth()->login($user);
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

The issue is that when the user comes back they are not remembered and automatically logged in. How can I do this with Socialite?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, have you found a solution so far?

Comment: No I have not figured this out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods), passing `true` as the second argument of `login()` will set the remember token.

`// Login and "remember" the given user... Auth::login($user, true);`

The `Auth` facade and `auth()` helper function access the same object.